# file_put_contents fails to create file in the included path

Tags: php

I am trying to create a text file in the desktop.I created an included path using set_include_path() but the file is created in my xampp/htdocs folder.How can i create the folder in my desktop??Is it possible??

```
set_include_path(',;c:/users/shimantta/Desktop');

echo file_put_contents("/test.txt","Hello World. Testing!",FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

Comment: Ok, so you've got answers now. What's working or not with the ones given?

Comment: selected an answer from the answers i've got so far.Check them out for yourself if you have any suggestions :)

Comment: Glad to see a solution was found for you, *cheers*

Comment: _“SO is threatening to block my asking privileges.So,at least don't down vote if this question looks inappropriate for this site.”_ – instead of trying to tell people what not to do with your question, you should rather work on improving your way of asking questions …

Comment: roger that!! ii i put that statement at front because i  didn't want that my asking privileges revoked by this site due to some downvote.in case you haven't noticed this question is well accepted by the community.I think that's an improvement :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The include path is the path that PHP searches when you include/require a file, not when you write to a file.

> **include_path** Specifies a list of directories where the require, include, fopen(),
>   file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions look for files.

Just give the complete path:

```
file_put_contents("c:/users/shimantta/Desktop/test.txt", "Hello World. Testing!");
```

This will only work if the user running the script or the user running the webserver has permission to write to that directory.

Comment: thanks ,it worked well !!  will file_put_contents() always  looks for file in the same folder where the .php file is ??

Comment: Yes.  If you don't specify a path then it is the current directory of the executing script.

Answer (score 2):

Your "/" put it in the root folder of your installation

```
file_put_contents("test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
```

will put it in the current directory of the current main page

```
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
```

wil put it in the current script directory (if included).

If you want to put it in another directory, just tell the path

```
file_put_contents("/path/to/test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
```

For windows, you might have to replace backslashes `/path/to/test.txt` with double backslashes `\\path\\to\\test.txt`

If you want to use FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH you have to remove the slash (which indicates an absolute path), and use the windows backslashes in your include path definition, specify your Desktop at first option. I think the file should exist before.

```
set_include_path("c:\\users\\shimantta\\Desktop;.");
echo file_put_contents("test.txt","Hello World. Testing!", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

EDIT: you can know the path where the test.txt will be with the function 
`stream_resolve_include_path("test.txt")`

Comment: i tried the double backslashes ,but it didn't create any text file in the desktop!!

Comment: Try testing your set_include_path directive with a simple include of a file from your desktop (txt or php)

Comment: i still don't get you !!

Comment: Your file must exist before. If you fail to include it, you won't be able to write it. Read here fore more information http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/08c9m5sn21/problem-with-include-path-and-write-based-file-functions

Answer (score 2):

[**`set_include_path`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) does **not** specify the active directory, but the directory where to look in case you want to include a file. For instance:

```
set_include_path('C:\php\libs\');
include_once('lib.php');
```

What you are looking for is [**`chdir`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) that **changes the active directory** . So the following code will write your file to `C:\documents\`:

```
chdir('C:\documents\');
file_put_contents('test.txt',"Test");
```

Or you can specify the entire path yourself:

```
file_put_contents('C:\documents\test.txt',"Test");
```

Answer (score -1):

For dynamically create robots.txt in the website root folder.

```
$data = "User-agent: *\nAllow: /wp-content/uploads/\nAllow: /wp-content/plugins/\nDisallow: /wp-admin/\n\n";
$data .= "Sitemap: {$site_url[ 'scheme' ]}://{$site_url[ 'host' ]}/sitemap_index.xml";

file_put_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/robots.txt', $data, 0 );
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from it. How does your answer relate to the initial question?

Comment: Original intention of this question was not to crate a file in root directory rather create it in a directory provided by the OP which is other than the root directory.